# Edit property based on library variant gradle android

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an android project with native part in it. I would like to build my native code with different flags, depending on buildType and productFlavor, for instance:

```
android {
    project.ext.buildFlags = ['-j16', 'all']
    buildTypes {
        debug { project.ext.buildFlags.add('NDK_DEBUG=1')}
    }
    productFlavors {
        pretty {project.ext.buildFlags.add('PRETTY')}
        ugly {project.ext.buildFlags.add('UGLY')}
    }

    task buildNativeCode(type: Exec) {
        commandLine 'ndk-build', project.ext.buildFlags
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }
}
```

So, for uglyDebug I would like to build my native library with 'UGLY', and 'NDK_DEBUG' flags, prettyDebug with 'PRETTY' and 'NDK_DEBUG' flags and so on. However, they are always added, regardless of the chosen configuration. From what I gather, this is done during project evaluation and I don't know how to set it up properly. For now I ended up creating many buildNativeXXX tasks that have pretty much the same content. I would love to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands to modify any tasks afterwards:

```
afterEvaluate {
    productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
        buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->

        project.ext.buildFlags.add('NDK_DEBUG=1')

        if (productFlavorName.equals("pretty")) {
           //enter code here
            project.ext.buildFlags.add('PRETTY')
        } else {
            project.ext.buildFlags.add('UGLY')
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Now you have full control of how gradle adds the buildFlags for you. :)

If you want to use the buildConfig variables, you can set them using:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "COMMIT_HASH", "HASH123456789"
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work. (aside from the fact you should compare .name property of productFlavors and buildTypes). It will iterate over each and every productFlavor and BuildType. Therefore, even if I choose uglyRelease, I will have NDK_DEBUG=1, PRETTY and UGLY in my buildFlags list.